# merging by common value in R

Tags: r, csv

The number of observations decreases significantly after merging two .csv files by common values. I have confirmed that two files have the common values manually.

This problem is something I've never encountered before and cannot figure out why this is happening. Could you please help?

Here is the code:

```
GII <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peoplecure/FunTravel/master/Gender%20Inequality%20Index.csv")
eGOV <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peoplecure/FunTravel/master/EGOV_DATA_2018.csv")
data <- merge(GII, eGOV, by="country")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I got it. I added these options: `header = T, strip.white = T, na.strings = c(""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and now `data` contains 181 observations. Strings were being imported as factors and the factors didn't match. Also, there are countries with stray white space that needed removal.

```
library(dplyr)
GII <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peoplecure/FunTravel/master/Gender%20Inequality%20Index.csv", header = T, strip.white = T, na.strings = c(""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% rename(country = ï..country)
eGOV <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peoplecure/FunTravel/master/EGOV_DATA_2018.csv", header = T, strip.white = T, na.strings = c(""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data <- merge(GII, eGOV, by="country")
```

Comment: Thanks! My only suggestion is adding the library for the pipe, and I had to change `rename(country = ï..country)`. Aside from that, it worked perfectly!